# To redirect the page to current instead of logout page

Tags: magento

I am working on logout button of magento. Now when i click on logout button it is going to logout page and redirect to the current page.

In the logout page template

```
<div class="page-head">
    <h3><?php echo $this->__("You're now Logged Out") ?></h3>
</div>
<p><?php echo $this->__('You have been successfully logged out and will be redirected to our homepage in 5 seconds.') ?></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){ location.href = '<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'},5000);
</script>
```

and in the customer.xml i found

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="customer_logout" template="customer/logout.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Now i want to redirect the page to direct current page instead of going to logout page. Hope you understand and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you took a look at the existing Magento code that handles logout ?

Class `Mage_Customer_AccountController`

```
/**
 * Customer logout action
 */
public function logoutAction()
{
    $this->_getSession()->logout()
        ->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl());

    $this->_redirect('*/*/logoutSuccess');
}
```

See the "setBeforeAuthUrl()" function ? Try to play with it to inject your current URL which you can retrieve with : `Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();`

Answer (score 0):

You could try change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){ location.href = '<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'},5000);
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){ location.href = document.referrer},5000);
</script>
```